# What are the difference between drupal 8 and 9

Tags: drupal

Need to understand the main differences between drupal 8 and drupal 9, apart from symphony update ?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from symphony some changes are:-

- Deprecated codes is removed. For more details how and why it is removed can refer https://www.drupal.org/docs/understanding-drupal/how-drupal-9-was-made-and-what-is-included/how-and-why-we-deprecated-code
- If you are running Drupal 9 on Apache, at least version 2.4.7 is required.
- Drupal 9 requires at least PHP 7.3. PHP 7.4 is also supported but not required. PHP 8 is not yet supported.
  Refernce - https://www.drupal.org/docs/understanding-drupal/how-drupal-9-was-made-and-what-is-included/environment-requirements-of
- The Place Blocks and SimpleTest modules have been removed from core. Reference - https://www.drupal.org/docs/understanding-drupal/how-drupal-9-is-made-and-what-is-included/which-modules-have-been-removed

Comment: https://www.droptica.com/blog/drupal-8-vs-drupal-9-it-time-upgrade/#:~:text=What's%20the%20difference%20between%20Drupal,of%20almost%20all%20deprecated%20functions.